# How to stop processing until a file is selected when ShinyFileChoose processing is performed

Tags: r, shiny

We are currently developing a Shiny app.
When I read a file with ShinyFileChoose, I want to store the read file in a variable and connect it to subsequent processing.
Therefore, I want to stop the process while selecting a file with ShinyFileChoose.
What should I do?

The sample code is below.

```
library ("shiny")
library ("shinyWidgets")

ui <-fluidPage (
  shinyFilesButton ('file','Reading file ...','choose file', FALSE),
      textOutput ("OUTPUT_TEXT")
)

server <-function (input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent (input $ file, {
    
    volumes <-c ("Documents" = Sys.getenv ("HOME"))
    shinyFileChoose (input,'file', session = session, roots = volumes, filetypes = c ('','txt'))
    
    unlistfile <-unlist (input $ file)
    filename <-c (unlistfile [2] [1])
    
    output $ OUTPUT_TEXT <-renderText ({
      paste0 (volumes, "\\", filename)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here, the file path and file name are output to textOutput by the process of paste0.
I would like to replace this process with the process of read_csv () and connect it to the process of reading the file.
However, since processing does not stop with shinyFileChoose, input $ file is processed with NA and an error occurs.

If anyone knows the countermeasures, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <-fluidPage (
  shinyFilesButton ('file','Reading file ...','choose file', FALSE),
  tableOutput("OUTPUT_TABLE")
)

server <-function (input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent (input$file, {
    volumes <- c("Documents" = Sys.getenv ("HOME"))
    shinyFileChoose (input,'file', session = session, roots = volumes, filetypes = c ('','txt'))
    if(length(input$file) <= 1) return({})
    output$OUTPUT_TABLE <- renderTable ({
      df <- read.csv(input$file$files[[1]][[3]])
      df
    })
  })
}

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments .　but An error has occurred　「Error in [[:」

Comment: Sorry, your comment seems to be incomplete. I tested this on couple of files on my system and it works without any error.

Comment: understood.
Is it a version issue? There is no problem with closing this once.

Comment: works! Thanks. Not a very popular question, but your response helped at least one person (me)